# fastest way to determine if a bit is set in a integer data type

Tags: c, algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I have a method that computes a hash value as per some specific algorithm.

```
uint8_t cal_hash(uint64_t _in_data) {
    uint8_t hash;
    // algorithm
    // bit at hash[0] = XOR of some specific bits in _in_data
    // repeat above statement for other indexed bits of hash 
    return hash;
}
```

I want to know what could be the most efficient way to access and set corresponding bits in an  integer datatype.
I have already tried things like

```
(((x) & (1<<(n)))?1:0)
```

to determine if a bit is 1 or 0 at any index. Anything better than this ?

Comment: My main objective is to minimize the number of times i have to use the shift operator.

Answer (score 3):

Your first concern should be to have a correct and portable version. Compilers nowadays will then optimize such bit operations quite cleverly.

You should always take care that the mask you are using corresponds to the data type that you are testing. Using an `int` or `unsigned` might not be enough since you are interested in the bits of a `uint64_t` and shifting for more than there are bits is undefined behavior.

In your case you would probably use something like

```
(UINT64_C(1) << (n))
```

for the mask. If you want to do this in a more generic way you'd have to obtain a `1` of your base type by something like

```
(1 ? 1U : (X))
```

alltogether in a macro

```
#define MASK(X, N) ((1 ? 1U : (X)) << (N))
```

and then the test could look like

```
#define BIT(X, N) !!((X) & MASK(X, N))
```

Comment: Is there something I'm missing about the ternary operator? Would 1 ? Foo : Bar not _always_ result in Foo? And left-shifting on signed and unsigned types are always logic shifts so why even bother with types?

Comment: @Kenneth, sure, but the type of the return value is determined from the type of the two expressions. Then shifting signed types can result in overflow and thus undefined behavior. We have to bother with types, because `(1U << N)` will always be `unsigned`, usually of width 32, and lead to UB, again, if `N` is 32 or more. Here the OP was interested in the bits of an `uint64_t`.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a speed vs. memory type question. (Updated with MrSmith42s suggestion):

If you really want speed I would define a mask for each bit a compare that. Perhaps something like:

```
const uint8_t BitMask[] = { 0x1, 0x2, 0x4, 0x8, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80 };

/* Find out if LSB is set */
if( hash & BitMask[0] ) { ... }
```

The problem with shifts is that it uses an instruction per shift whereas a fixed mask will only have a single memory acces before the comparison.

Comment: I would simply use an array where the index is the bit to test and the values are the corresponding mask. But its the same idea.

Comment: That will be a lot clearer as the array name will show intent. I will update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Yes, want i am really looking is for faster computation. what really worries me is the number of times i will use the shift operator for 64 bit value

Comment: Then I would say just created the array and then sacrifice the 64B of memory to hold it :) You should know that you can use the shift operator in constant expressions without problems. That is translated at compile time. I.e. the above decleration could be written as { 1<<1, 1<<2, ... }. It is still tedious to create the array but perhaps a little clearer and less error prone.

Comment: @Kenneth: The Array will need 64*8Bytes because each of the 64 masks has size 64 bits = 8 bytes. Therefore we need the 512bytes. ;-)

Comment: @MrSmith42 I suppose you are right but that would depend on how the compiler lays it out in memory. On my 32-bit linux the BitMask array I defined above has size 8, not 32*8.

Comment: @Kenneth: 8 is correct for your example, but for 64bit mask you need an array with 64 entries where each entry has size 64bit.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I just realised my obvious and flawed logic. Of course you are correct. I apologize and will go and read a book...

Answer (score 3):

For finding a bit that is set quickly, try this:

```
int oneBit = x & ~(x-1);
```

After this, `oneBit` will have ONLY the lowest bit of X set.
*(eg, if `x` was `1011 0100`, oneBit will be `0000 0100`, eg. just the lowest bit)*

After that, you can turn off the lowest bit with:

```
x &= x-1;
```

*(eg: if `x` was `1011 0100`, new `x` should be `1011 0000`)*

Then you can repeat the first operation to find the next lowest bit that was set.

This has the great advantage that you don't spend time "testing" a bit only to find out that its zero.
It gets you directly to those bits that are set, and skips bits that are zero.

Here's example code that shows it in action:

```
int main(void)
{
    int x = 180;  // 1011 0100

    while (x)
    {
        printf("Low Bit is: %d\n", x & ~(x-1));
        x &= (x-1);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Low Bit is: 4    // eg. 0000 0100
Low Bit is: 16   // eg. 0001 0000
Low Bit is: 32   // eg. 0010 0000
Low Bit is: 128  // eg. 1000 0000
```